# How to not allow export as .CSV if any null values exist

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tab in excel that has about 50 columns. I export this tab as a .CSV file and upload it into a database. I am currently using this VBA code to export the .CSV file:

```
 Sub ExportAsCSV()

 Dim MyFileName As String
 Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

 Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

 Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
 With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
 End With

 'Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
 MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
 TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

There are certain columns in this export tab that will have "null" (actual word null) if the connected cells in other sheets are not filled in. How can I add to this existing VBA code to not allow an export if there are any null (the word, not blanks) values? Also how can a box pop up telling you that it wont export due to nulls?

Comment: Please fix your code's formatting, as it currently stands it would not compile. Add line breaks where they're needed please.

Comment: Also, we are missing information from you - which columns shouldn't contain null? How many rows does your file have? Is it a dynamically sized file?

Comment: Please don't use hard coded lengths when looking for file extensions, or anywhere else...just find the correct position and replace it: `MyFileName = Left(CurrentWB.FullName, InStrRev(CurrentWB.FullName, ".")) & "csv"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code's structure and added a test at the start which checks to make sure you have no "null" values anywhere on your `ActiveSheet` - if you do, it will throw a pop-up then exit the macro.

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, "null") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Null values exist in the range - exiting sub.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)

With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Although this code should work, most programmers would frown at relying on Worksheet Functions, due to speed issues.  It would be better to copy the `Range` to a `Variant`, then loop through the array and exit at first sign of "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot more elaborate, but I think it's the right way to do it.  Plus, it activates the first "null" cell for the end user to look at.

Add the following lines to the top of your code:

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()
Dim NullAddress As String

    NullAddress = FindNull(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If NullAddress <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(NullAddress).Activate
        MsgBox "Cannot Export due to ""null"" value in cell"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    '
    '
End Sub
```

which replies on the test function to do the heavy lifting:

```
Function FindNull(Target As Excel.Range) As String
Const NullValue As String = "null"
Dim vData 'As Variant
Dim Row As Long, Col As Long

    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        vData = Target
        If IsArray(vData) Then
            For Row = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
                For Col = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
                    If vData(Row, Col) = NullValue Then
                        ' Return the Address of the first Null value found & Exit
                        FindNull = Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Cells(1).Row + Row - 1, Target.Cells(1).Column + Col - 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Else
            If vData = NullValue Then FindNull = Target.Address
        End If
    End If
End Function
```